# Jackson deserialization of list of objects with kotlin

Tags: xml, kotlin, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize this simple xml using jackson and kotlin:

```xml
<root>
  <nesteds>
    <nested testAttr="attr1">val1</nested>
    <nested testAttr="attr2">val2</nested>
  </nesteds>
</root>
```

I work with jackson-core 2.15, jackson-dataformat-xml 2.15 and jackson-module-kotlin 2.15.

My xml mapper is configured like this

```
XmlMapper().registerKotlinModule().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```

My model is as follows:

```kotlin
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class KotlinRootTestClass(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "nesteds")
    val nestedList: Nesteds
)

data class Nesteds(
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false) val nested: List<KotlinNested>
)

data class KotlinNested(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true) val testAttr: String,
    @JacksonXmlText(value = true) val value: String
)
```

and this code does deserialization

```kotlin
xmlMapper.readValue(xml.trim(), CeneoOffersList::class.java)
```

Sadly it does not work and I get following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid definition for property '' (of type `com.empik.marketplace.feed.converter.infrastructure.KotlinNested`): Could not find creator property with name '' (known Creator properties: [testAttr, value])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:62)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadPropertyDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1910)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:636)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:277)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:415)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:350)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:621)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:188)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:836)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:550)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DelegatingDeserializer.resolve(DelegatingDeserializer.java:60)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findNonContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:539)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DelegatingDeserializer.resolve(DelegatingDeserializer.java:60)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:654)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4956)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4826)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3772)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3740)
    at CeneoFeedSerializationSpec.deserialize(CeneoFeedSerializationSpec.groovy:49)
```

What is funny is that I got this xml by creating kotlin object and converting it to string via json...

```kotlin
xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(kotlinNestedClass)
```

I suppose that is somehow related to this issue https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/153 but non of the workarounds work for me (I tried using annotations with `get:` and `field:` prefixes).

Does anybody knows solution to this? For now I will just declare this model in java for which deserialization works, but I would love to avoid it. I suppose that I need to throw in some more annotations into data classes but honestly I tried a lot already and nothing seems to work.

Comment: That's because your container ( `<nested>`) is named the same way as a leaf-node and lacks required attributes. Renaming it to e.g. `<nesteds>` (both in XML and Kotlin XML-annotation) should help

Comment: Sadly it is not this, I changed model so that it generates following xml
`<root><nesteds><nested testAttr="attr1">val1</nested><nested testAttr="attr2">val2</nested></nesteds></root>`

Model now looks like this

data class KotlinRootTestClass(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "nesteds")
    val nesteds: Nesteds
)



And still the same issue

Comment: edited question to reflect this change